# Android + Appium: Scroll inside ListView to specific position and click on it

Tags: java, android, listview, appium

can someone please help me with this.

**Task:** Open ListView element in Android App, scroll to specific position and click on it. If element wasn't found, than scroll to the bottom of the list and stop to search and drop the test with exception.
[image: app screenshot with structure]

//Yes, I have been looking for a solution on other questions, but I can't combine then to use in my case.

**What did i get:**

1) Test swipes inside ListView to specific position and clicks on it;

2) Test stacks in loop in the bottom of ListView.

**Questions:**

1) How to stop test with exception if specific position wasn't found when the bottom of ListView was reached?

2) Swipe looks like incorrect solution and seems there must be used another solution, or no?

code:

```
public void scrollToElementFromList (String keyword_locator){
// keyword_locator = (By.xpath("//*[@resource-id = 'android:id/text1'][@text = 'Spain']"))
    boolean token = false;
    while(!token) {
        if (this.isElementPresent(keyword_locator)){
            waitForElementAndClick(keyword_locator,"Cannot click selected element",3);
            token = true;
        } else {
            TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView"));
            int middleX = element.getLocation().getX() + element.getSize().getWidth() / 2;
            int upperY = element.getLocation().getY();
            int lowerY = upperY + element.getSize().getHeight() - 50;
            action.press(middleX, lowerY).waitAction(1200).moveTo(middleX, upperY).release().perform();
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your issue related to this [Github issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8637)

Comment: @KhaledLela How did my issue related on this? I dont see any stop functions with exception in this issue

Comment: I am also looking forward to a solution to scroll the screen till end having about 100-150 values and number of screens to be scrolled may change time to time.  TouchAction scrolls once based on dimensions of screen and not till the end scrolling across 10 or 15 pages.

Comment: Try this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[text()='Andorra']")).click();

Comment: @Deepak check for my solution in answer

Answer (score 1):

answer:

```
public void scrollToElementFromList (String locator, String keyword_locator, int max_swipes){
    By by = this.getLocatorByString(locator);
    boolean element_found = false;
    int already_swiped = 0;
    while(!element_found) {
        if (this.isElementPresent(keyword_locator)){
            waitForElementAndClick(keyword_locator,"Cannot click selected element",3);
            element_found = true;
        } else if (already_swiped > max_swipes){
            throw new AssertionError("Cannot find element by swiping up.");
        }
        else {
            TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
            int middleX = element.getLocation().getX() + element.getSize().getWidth() / 2;
            int upperY = element.getLocation().getY();
            int lowerY = upperY + element.getSize().getHeight() - 50;
            action.press(middleX, lowerY).waitAction(1200).moveTo(middleX, upperY).release().perform();
            ++already_swiped;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```